# Getting 404s in wp-admin after logged in

Tags: wp-admin, 404-error, dashboard

I'm successfully able to login but the links point to 404s until I correct them manually. Here's the step by step scenario:

1. Visited wp-admin/wp-login.php and login successfully say the dashboard link is localhost
2. When hovered over other links on the sidebar they don't have 'wp-admin' in them. For eg., it says localhost/edit.php instead of locahost/wp-admin/edit.php. When I correct it manually in the URL bar, it works but that's not how it's supposed to be.
3. After manually correcting and redirecting to the proper page, all he links now have 'wp-admin' in them.

I have tried downloading & replacing all the WP core files. I have also added a backslash to 'siteurl' & 'home' in wp-options which now point to http://localhost/ without any success.

Comment: Have you installed wordpress using wp-config.php ?

Comment: I don't know any other method to do so.

Comment: When you say: I have tried downloading & replacing all the WP core files.- did you remove the install and reinstall it via wp-config.php or did you just copy the files?

Comment: I replaced all the files except wp-config and wp-content

Comment: If you can I recommend to trash everything and do a total clean install